SuiteQL problem (netsuite) - one SQL fails, other 2 do not
I have 3 SQL that I send to NetSuite suiteql service.  One fails, the other 2 succeed.  I am talking the same account, using the same underlying code, but don't see what I am doing wrong.
For context, I am running this in a Python script, but in my examples below I just include the SQL and the Python output or error.  When I do a diff between all 3 SQL, there are minor differences, which I mention below.
First of all, the failed SQL.  Note that we have both and BUILTIN.DF(inv.location) not in ( 'Quarantine' ) and and coalesce(item.vendorname, ' ' ) not in ( '10' ), which the combination of both those is what seems to cause the problem:
SQL: SELECT item.id, nvl(itemId, 'null') as itemPartNumber,
            nvl(to_char(item.createdDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM' ), 'null' ) as ItemCreationDate,
            nvl(to_char(item.lastModifiedDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM' ), 'null' ) as ItemLastModifiedDate,
            coalesce(vendor.entityid, ' ') as VendorId,
            coalesce(item.vendorname, ' ' ) as ManufacturingAccount,
            nvl( to_char(sum(inv.quantityonhand)), '0' ) as qtyOnHand,
            nvl( to_char(sum(inv.quantityavailable)), '0' ) as qtyavailable,
            nvl( to_char(sum(inventoryloc.quantityonhand)), 'null' ) as qtyOnHand2,
            nvl( to_char(sum(inventoryloc.quantityintransit)), '0' ) as qtyInTransit,
            nvl( to_char(salesData.QuantityOnOrder), '0') As QuantityOnSalesOrder,
            nvl( to_char(poData.QuantityOnOrder), '0') As QuantityOnOrder,
            round(nvl( to_char(sum(inv.quantityonhand)), '0' ) + nvl( to_char(sum(inventoryloc.quantityintransit)), '0' )) as totalQtyOnHand
        
            from item
                left outer join inventoryBalance as inv on
                    inv.item = item.id
                    and BUILTIN.DF(inv.location) not in ( 'Quarantine' )
                left outer join inventoryitemlocations as inventoryloc on
                    inventoryloc.item = item.id
                    and inventoryLoc.location = inv.location
                left outer join
                    ( select item as venItem2, count(*) as cnt
                        from itemVendor as iv group by iv.item ) as countVenItem
                    on countVenItem.venItem2 = item.id
                left outer join itemVendor as venItem on
                    venItem.item = item.id and
                    ( venItem.preferredVendor = 'T' or countVenItem.cnt = 1 )
                left outer join vendor as vendor on vendor.id = venItem.vendor
                left outer join
                    ( select s.item as salesitem,
                        sum( nvl( s.itemcount, 0 ) -
                            nvl( SOLine.quantityPicked, 0 ) ) as QuantityOnOrder
                      from salesOrdered s
                        inner join transaction t on
                            s.transaction = t.id and
                            t.type = 'SalesOrd' and
                            t.voided = 'F' and
                            lower( BUILTIN.DF(t.Status)) not like '%close%' and
                            lower( BUILTIN.DF(t.Status)) not like '%cancel%'
                        inner join TransactionLine as SOLine on
                            SOLine.uniquekey = s.uniquekey and
                            SOLine.transaction = t.id and
                            -- s.itemcount > SOLine.quantityPicked and
                            nvl( SOLine.isClosed, 'F' ) = 'F' and
                            nvl2( to_char(s.uniquekey), 'F', 'T' ) = 'F'
                        left outer join subsidiary as subSO on subSO.id = SOLine.subsidiary
                      group by s.item ) as salesData on
                            salesData.salesitem = item.id
                left outer join
                    ( select POLine.item as poitem, sum( nvl(POLine.quantity, 0) -
                        nvl(POLine.quantityShipRecv, 0) ) as quantityOnOrder
                      from transaction as po
                        inner join transactionline as POLine on
                            POLine.transaction = po.id
                            and nvl( POLine.isClosed, 'F' ) != 'T'
                            and ( case
                                when nvl(POLine.QuantityShipRecv, 0) > 0 and
                                    nvl(POLine.Quantity, 0) > 0 and
                                    nvl(POLine.QuantityShipRecv, 0) >= nvl(POLine.Quantity, 0) then 'T'
                                else 'F'
                            end ) != 'T'
                            left outer join subsidiary as subPO on subPO.id = POLine.subsidiary
                      where po.type = 'PurchOrd'
                      and lower(po.status) not like '%cancel%'
                      and lower(po.status) not like '%close%'
                      and lower(po.status) not like '%fully billed%'
                      group by POLine.item ) as poData on
                        poData.poitem = item.id
        where 
                item.itemtype in ('InvtPart', 'Assembly')
                and nvl(item.isInactive, 'F' ) = 'F'
                and nvl(BUILTIN.DF(item.planningItemCategory), 'null' ) <> 'Discontinued'
                and coalesce(item.vendorname, ' ' ) not in ( '10' )
        group by
            item.id, nvl(itemId, 'null'),
            nvl(to_char(item.createdDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM' ), 'null' ),
            nvl(to_char(item.lastModifiedDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM' ), 'null' ),
            coalesce(vendor.entityid, ' '),
            coalesce(item.vendorname, ' ' ),
            nvl( to_char(salesData.QuantityOnOrder), '0'),
            nvl( to_char(poData.QuantityOnOrder), '0')
        
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wms/v10_odbc/bin/downloadNetsuiteActiveSkuBOHToCsv.py", line 482, in <module>
    asyncio.run(async_main(sys.argv))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 587, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/wms/v10_odbc/bin/downloadNetsuiteActiveSkuBOHToCsv.py", line 398, in async_main
    results = await ns.rest_api.suiteql(query, limit=1000, offset=0 )
  File "/home/wms/v9_odbc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/netsuite/rest_api.py", line 57, in suiteql
    **request_kw,
  File "/home/wms/v9_odbc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/netsuite/rest_api_base.py", line 45, in _request
    raise NetsuiteAPIRequestError(resp.status_code, resp.text)
netsuite.exceptions.NetsuiteAPIRequestError: HTTP400 - {"type":"https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-15.5.1","title":"Bad Request","status":400,"o:errorDetails":[{"detail":"Invalid search query. Detailed unprocessed description follows. Search error occurred: Invalid or unsupported search.","o:errorQueryParam":"q","o:errorCode":"INVALID_PARAMETER"}]}

And now one example that worked.  Note that we do NOT have and BUILTIN.DF(inv.location) not in ( 'Quarantine' ):
SQL: SELECT item.id, nvl(itemId, 'null') as itemPartNumber,
            nvl(to_char(item.createdDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM' ), 'null' ) as ItemCreationDate,
            nvl(to_char(item.lastModifiedDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM' ), 'null' ) as ItemLastModifiedDate,
            coalesce(vendor.entityid, ' ') as VendorId,
            coalesce(item.vendorname, ' ' ) as ManufacturingAccount,
            nvl( to_char(sum(inv.quantityonhand)), '0' ) as qtyOnHand,
            nvl( to_char(sum(inv.quantityavailable)), '0' ) as qtyavailable,
            nvl( to_char(sum(inventoryloc.quantityonhand)), 'null' ) as qtyOnHand2,
            nvl( to_char(sum(inventoryloc.quantityintransit)), '0' ) as qtyInTransit,
            nvl( to_char(salesData.QuantityOnOrder), '0') As QuantityOnSalesOrder,
            nvl( to_char(poData.QuantityOnOrder), '0') As QuantityOnOrder,
            round(nvl( to_char(sum(inv.quantityonhand)), '0' ) + nvl( to_char(sum(inventoryloc.quantityintransit)), '0' )) as totalQtyOnHand
        
            from item
                left outer join inventoryBalance as inv on
                    inv.item = item.id
                left outer join inventoryitemlocations as inventoryloc on
                    inventoryloc.item = item.id
                    and inventoryLoc.location = inv.location
                left outer join
                    ( select item as venItem2, count(*) as cnt
                        from itemVendor as iv group by iv.item ) as countVenItem
                    on countVenItem.venItem2 = item.id
                left outer join itemVendor as venItem on
                    venItem.item = item.id and
                    ( venItem.preferredVendor = 'T' or countVenItem.cnt = 1 )
                left outer join vendor as vendor on vendor.id = venItem.vendor
                left outer join
                    ( select s.item as salesitem,
                        sum( nvl( s.itemcount, 0 ) -
                            nvl( SOLine.quantityPicked, 0 ) ) as QuantityOnOrder
                      from salesOrdered s
                        inner join transaction t on
                            s.transaction = t.id and
                            t.type = 'SalesOrd' and
                            t.voided = 'F' and
                            lower( BUILTIN.DF(t.Status)) not like '%close%' and
                            lower( BUILTIN.DF(t.Status)) not like '%cancel%'
                        inner join TransactionLine as SOLine on
                            SOLine.uniquekey = s.uniquekey and
                            SOLine.transaction = t.id and
                            -- s.itemcount > SOLine.quantityPicked and
                            nvl( SOLine.isClosed, 'F' ) = 'F' and
                            nvl2( to_char(s.uniquekey), 'F', 'T' ) = 'F'
                        left outer join subsidiary as subSO on subSO.id = SOLine.subsidiary
                      group by s.item ) as salesData on
                            salesData.salesitem = item.id
                left outer join
                    ( select POLine.item as poitem, sum( nvl(POLine.quantity, 0) -
                        nvl(POLine.quantityShipRecv, 0) ) as quantityOnOrder
                      from transaction as po
                        inner join transactionline as POLine on
                            POLine.transaction = po.id
                            and nvl( POLine.isClosed, 'F' ) != 'T'
                            and ( case
                                when nvl(POLine.QuantityShipRecv, 0) > 0 and
                                    nvl(POLine.Quantity, 0) > 0 and
                                    nvl(POLine.QuantityShipRecv, 0) >= nvl(POLine.Quantity, 0) then 'T'
                                else 'F'
                            end ) != 'T'
                            left outer join subsidiary as subPO on subPO.id = POLine.subsidiary
                      where po.type = 'PurchOrd'
                      and lower(po.status) not like '%cancel%'
                      and lower(po.status) not like '%close%'
                      and lower(po.status) not like '%fully billed%'
                      group by POLine.item ) as poData on
                        poData.poitem = item.id
        where 
                item.itemtype in ('InvtPart', 'Assembly')
                and nvl(item.isInactive, 'F' ) = 'F'
                and nvl(BUILTIN.DF(item.planningItemCategory), 'null' ) <> 'Discontinued'
                and coalesce(item.vendorname, ' ' ) not in ( '10' )
        group by
            item.id, nvl(itemId, 'null'),
            nvl(to_char(item.createdDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM' ), 'null' ),
            nvl(to_char(item.lastModifiedDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM' ), 'null' ),
            coalesce(vendor.entityid, ' '),
            coalesce(item.vendorname, ' ' ),
            nvl( to_char(salesData.QuantityOnOrder), '0'),
            nvl( to_char(poData.QuantityOnOrder), '0')
        
Page 1 JSON printed to $DIR/BOHCHECK/BOHCheck20241007163133_Pg1.json
  Opened file $DIR/STE/BOHCheck20241007163133.csv
  Writing page 1 elapsed time: 00:00:00:22 at 2024-10-07 16:31:55
Page 2 JSON printed to $DIR/BOHCHECK/BOHCheck20241007163133_Pg2.json
  Writing page 2 elapsed time: 00:00:00:09 at 2024-10-07 16:32:05
Page 3 JSON printed to $DIR/BOHCHECK/BOHCheck20241007163133_Pg3.json
  Writing page 3 elapsed time: 00:00:00:07 at 2024-10-07 16:32:12
Total processing elapsed time: 00:00:00:39 at 2024-10-07 16:32:12

Finally, the last SQL that worked.  In this case, we don't have the and coalesce(item.vendorname, ' ' ) not in ( '10' ):
SQL: SELECT item.id, nvl(itemId, 'null') as itemPartNumber,
            nvl(to_char(item.createdDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM' ), 'null' ) as ItemCreationDate,
            nvl(to_char(item.lastModifiedDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM' ), 'null' ) as ItemLastModifiedDate,
            coalesce(vendor.entityid, ' ') as VendorId,
            coalesce(item.vendorname, ' ' ) as ManufacturingAccount,
            nvl( to_char(sum(inv.quantityonhand)), '0' ) as qtyOnHand,
            nvl( to_char(sum(inv.quantityavailable)), '0' ) as qtyavailable,
            nvl( to_char(sum(inventoryloc.quantityonhand)), 'null' ) as qtyOnHand2,
            nvl( to_char(sum(inventoryloc.quantityintransit)), '0' ) as qtyInTransit,
            nvl( to_char(salesData.QuantityOnOrder), '0') As QuantityOnSalesOrder,
            nvl( to_char(poData.QuantityOnOrder), '0') As QuantityOnOrder,
            round(nvl( to_char(sum(inv.quantityonhand)), '0' ) + nvl( to_char(sum(inventoryloc.quantityintransit)), '0' )) as totalQtyOnHand
        
            from item
                left outer join inventoryBalance as inv on
                    inv.item = item.id
                    and BUILTIN.DF(inv.location) not in ( 'Quarantine' )
                left outer join inventoryitemlocations as inventoryloc on
                    inventoryloc.item = item.id
                    and inventoryLoc.location = inv.location
                left outer join
                    ( select item as venItem2, count(*) as cnt
                        from itemVendor as iv group by iv.item ) as countVenItem
                    on countVenItem.venItem2 = item.id
                left outer join itemVendor as venItem on
                    venItem.item = item.id and
                    ( venItem.preferredVendor = 'T' or countVenItem.cnt = 1 )
                left outer join vendor as vendor on vendor.id = venItem.vendor
                left outer join
                    ( select s.item as salesitem,
                        sum( nvl( s.itemcount, 0 ) -
                            nvl( SOLine.quantityPicked, 0 ) ) as QuantityOnOrder
                      from salesOrdered s
                        inner join transaction t on
                            s.transaction = t.id and
                            t.type = 'SalesOrd' and
                            t.voided = 'F' and
                            lower( BUILTIN.DF(t.Status)) not like '%close%' and
                            lower( BUILTIN.DF(t.Status)) not like '%cancel%'
                        inner join TransactionLine as SOLine on
                            SOLine.uniquekey = s.uniquekey and
                            SOLine.transaction = t.id and
                            -- s.itemcount > SOLine.quantityPicked and
                            nvl( SOLine.isClosed, 'F' ) = 'F' and
                            nvl2( to_char(s.uniquekey), 'F', 'T' ) = 'F'
                        left outer join subsidiary as subSO on subSO.id = SOLine.subsidiary
                      group by s.item ) as salesData on
                            salesData.salesitem = item.id
                left outer join
                    ( select POLine.item as poitem, sum( nvl(POLine.quantity, 0) -
                        nvl(POLine.quantityShipRecv, 0) ) as quantityOnOrder
                      from transaction as po
                        inner join transactionline as POLine on
                            POLine.transaction = po.id
                            and nvl( POLine.isClosed, 'F' ) != 'T'
                            and ( case
                                when nvl(POLine.QuantityShipRecv, 0) > 0 and
                                    nvl(POLine.Quantity, 0) > 0 and
                                    nvl(POLine.QuantityShipRecv, 0) >= nvl(POLine.Quantity, 0) then 'T'
                                else 'F'
                            end ) != 'T'
                            left outer join subsidiary as subPO on subPO.id = POLine.subsidiary
                      where po.type = 'PurchOrd'
                      and lower(po.status) not like '%cancel%'
                      and lower(po.status) not like '%close%'
                      and lower(po.status) not like '%fully billed%'
                      group by POLine.item ) as poData on
                        poData.poitem = item.id
        where 
                item.itemtype in ('InvtPart', 'Assembly')
                and nvl(item.isInactive, 'F' ) = 'F'
                and nvl(BUILTIN.DF(item.planningItemCategory), 'null' ) <> 'Discontinued'
        group by
            item.id, nvl(itemId, 'null'),
            nvl(to_char(item.createdDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM' ), 'null' ),
            nvl(to_char(item.lastModifiedDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM' ), 'null' ),
            coalesce(vendor.entityid, ' '),
            coalesce(item.vendorname, ' ' ),
            nvl( to_char(salesData.QuantityOnOrder), '0'),
            nvl( to_char(poData.QuantityOnOrder), '0')
        
Page 1 JSON printed to $DIR/BOHCHECK/BOHCheck20241007163450_Pg1.json
  Opened file $DIR/STE/BOHCheck20241007163450.csv
  Writing page 1 elapsed time: 00:00:00:10 at 2024-10-07 16:35:01
Page 2 JSON printed to $DIR/BOHCHECK/BOHCheck20241007163450_Pg2.json
  Writing page 2 elapsed time: 00:00:00:08 at 2024-10-07 16:35:09
Page 3 JSON printed to $DIR/BOHCHECK/BOHCheck20241007163450_Pg3.json
  Writing page 3 elapsed time: 00:00:00:07 at 2024-10-07 16:35:16
Total processing elapsed time: 00:00:00:25 at 2024-10-07 16:35:16

